# getElementsByClassName > get children

Tags: javascript, dom, getelementbyid

I have this HTML code:

```
<div id="channels_0">
   <div id="channels">
      <h4 class="date"><span id="date">Sat 22nd Sep</span> @ 
      <span id="time">12:45</span></h4>
      <h3 class="teems"><span id="date">Swansea City v Everton </span></h3>
      <h4 class="tv"><span id="mychannels"></span>Sky Sports 2/Sky Sports 2 HD</h4>
   </div>
</div>
```

I have this JS:

```
document.getElementById('channels').innerText)
```

Which outputs:

```
Sat 22nd Sep @ 12:45
Swansea City v Everton
Sky Sports 2/Sky Sports 2 HD
```

How do i get a handle and output the individual items like: mychannels, or teems or time or date
i.e. i need to get the children, how is this done?

I have tried:

```
document.getElementById('channels').getElementsByTagName('date').value;
```

and

```
document.getElementsByClassName('date').value;
```

and others, but still cant seem to get a handle on it.

Comment: A lot of these fields can be accessed immediately by their own ID. You don't have the same ID at several places in the document, right?

Comment: Have you tried document.getElementById('channels').children ?

Comment: Both `getElementsByClassName` and `getElementsByTagName` return a _Node list_, even if there is only 1 element in it, so `document.getElementsByClassName('MyClass')[0].value` works, leave out the `[0]` though, and it won't

Answer (score 10):

These are tasks which are made much easier with a DOM-centric Javascript library like jQuery, for which the code would be:

```
$('#channels .date').text();
```

An important thing to realise with native methods is that whereas `getElementById` will always return a single element, methods like `getElementsByClass` return collections of elements, which is one of the reasons your code isn't working (the other reason being that `value` is not a standard DOM element property: it's used for retrieving the current value of form elements).

The following document method, `querySelectorAll` works in all modern browser and IE from version 8 upwards (`getElementsByClassName` doesn't work in IE until version 9):

```
document.querySelectorAll('#channels .date');
```

To get the combined `innerHTML` of any elements this turns up (in your code it's just one, but it could be more), you will need to store that collection of elements in a variable and then loop through them to extract their `innerHTML` one by one:

```
var dates     = document.querySelectorAll('#channels .date');
var datesText = (function(){
    var string = '';

    for(var i = 0; i < dates.length; i++){
        string += dates[i].innerText;
    }

    return string;
}());
```

Comment: Hi Barney, thanks for this.
I have tried this: $('#channels .date').text();
and it outputs all the items in my list:

Sat 22nd Sep @ 12:45Sun 23rd Sep @ 13:30Sun 23rd Sep @ 16:00Sat 29th Sep @ 12:45Sat 29th Sep @ 17:30Sun 30th Sep @ 16:00.... i.e. all the dates.

how do i get the first?

Comment: the data i am trying to get is here: http://www.visualdesign.ie/_dev/_tmp/www/epl.html

Comment: `$('#channels .date:eq(0)').text()` will get the first matched element's text. `:eq(0)` isn't standard CSS – it's something the jQuery team added in for DOM traversal: it assumes that any selector can return any number of elements, and the number you pass to `eq` determines which one to pull out of that. Nice looking site, BTW.

Comment: thanks mate. i try this: `$myDate = $('#channels .date:eq(0)').text()` ... with a log `console.log('myDate is ('+$myDate+')');` and i get this: `myDate is ()` ... i try it with `date:eq(1)` and `date:eq(2)` etc, and same story. But the  `$('#channels .date').text();` output all normally... any ideas? thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
var channels = document.getElementById('channels');

var date = channels.getElementsByClassName("date")[0];
var datePart = date.getElementById("date").innerHTML;
var timePart = date.getElementById("time").innerHTML;

var teems = channels.getElementsByClassName("teems")[0];
var teemsDate = teems.getElementById("date").innerHTML;

var tv = channels.getElementsByClassName("tv")[0];
var tvChannel = tv.innerText;
```

Also note that your `id`s should be unique across the entire document.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/MLJ6N/)**.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to get all the the direct descendants of the root node, use this,

```
 var rootChildren = document.getElementById('channels_0').childNodes;
```

If you need all the child Nodes of the root node, use this

```
 var allChildren = document.getElementById('channels_0').getElementsByTagName('*');
```

Or to get all the spans of the root node, since thats where the text is, try this,

```
 document.getElementById('channels').getElementsByTagName('span');
```

I am not sure if this is what you want to accomplish. Though.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
document.getElementById('mychannels').innerHTML
```

if u dont have same id at different places